# How to center title in CollapsingToolbarLayout with back icon visible

Tags: android, material-design

As you can see in the picture. The title is slightly off centered because of the back button on the top-left.

How can I center the title?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I dig around the source code in CollapsingToolbarLayout and finally find a trick to center the title even when the back button is visible.

**How to**
1. Add this class to your code:

```
class CollapseLayoutCenteredTitleToolbar @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.toolbarStyle) : Toolbar(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b)
    (0 until childCount).forEach {
        val view = getChildAt(it)
        // 除了CollapsingToolbarLayout，没有谁会加一个纯的View进来
        if (view.javaClass == View::class.java) {
            view.left = 0
        }
    }
}
```

}

2. Change your layout to something like this:

   ```
           <demo.CollapseLayoutCenteredTitleToolbar
               android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
               app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
               app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
               />
       </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
   ```
3. Enjoy
   [image: centered]